# How can we pass headers arguments with whitespaces in graphql?

Tags: graphql

API is working absolutely fine in graphql playground.

But when I tested the same API with the same data in postman it gave me an error.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Context creation failed: Permission denied",
            "statusCode": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

I was passing the access token in the header

like:

```
{"authorization":"Bearer accesstoken"}
```

In terms of postman data is going in this format

```
authorization: Bearer accesstoken
```

The issue is with the white space in the Bearer and access token

Is there any way we can pass a value with whitespaces in header?

I have tried using `%20` and `_`.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think the whitespace is the issue here? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: there is a white space between bearer and accesstoken

Comment: It is expected that there is a whitespace, and what you're describing is already the way I'd expect to work. You stated "The issue is with the white space in the Bearer and access token" but you did not specify what makes you say that.  A header with `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>` is expected, you don't need to encode the space.

Comment: I was also expecting it to work. But unfortunately not working.

Comment: Then I think you should remove "The issue is with the white space in the Bearer and access token" from the question and change the title, because you are claiming to know the cause when you do not.

Comment: Well, this issue was from the backend. They were not handling data correctly.